# Why there is no replacement of the preprocessor directives?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

The format of define preprocessor directives are:

```
#ifndef  SIZE
#define SIZE 10
int hello[SIZE];
#endif
```

But when I look at the following code, there is no replacement for the preprocessor directives:

```
#ifndef CREDIT_CARD_H                    // Avoid repeated expansion
#define CREDIT_CARD_H

#include <string>                        // Provides string
#include <iostream>                      // Provides ostream

class CreditCard
{
    public:
        CreditCard(const std::string& no,    // Constructor
                   const std::string& nm, int lim, double bal = 0);

        // Accessor functions
        std::string    getNumber()const    { return number; }
        std::string    getName() const     { return name; }
        double         getBalance() const  { return balance; }
        int            getLimit() const    { return limit; }

        bool chargeIt(double price);       // Make a charge
        void makePayment(double payment);  // Make a payment

    private:                               // Private member data
        std::string    number;             // Credit card number
        std::string name;                  // Card owner's name
        int            limit;              // Credit limit
        double        balance;             // Credit card balance
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const CreditCard& c);
#endif
```

What does this mean?

Comment: What do you mean "there is no replacement"? Do you mean that they are not used anywhere, or they are used but not expanded properly?

Comment: There's no replacement string for `CREDIT_CARD_H`. Makes sense, since it's never used in places where it should be replaced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can say `#define FOO`, which means that `#ifdef FOO` will be true, but `FOO` doesn't have any replacement text. This is useful precisely for conditional checks like the include guards.

It can also be useful for platform-specific extensions, which you want to be empty in the general case:

```
#ifdef WIN32
#  define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define API
#endif

API void foo();
```

Answer (score 3):

That type of directive pastes in the file depending on the condition:

```
#ifndef  SIZE

//whatever

#endif
```

Whatever is between the `#ifndef` and `#endif` is seen by the compiler **only if** `SIZE` wasn't defined.

The same happens for the second piece of code:

```
#ifndef CREDIT_CARD_H                   // avoid repeated expansion
#define CREDIT_CARD_H

//....

#endif
```

The class definition and includes will only be seen if `CREDIT_CARD_H` was not defined beforehand. This is known as an **include guard.**

You don't have to define a macro as something, you can just say `#ifdef SIZE` without actually "setting" size to anything, just defining it.

Answer (score 1):

It's an **include guard** to ensure that the file only gets included once.

```
#include "CreditCard.h"
#include "CreditCard.h"
```

The second time it's included CREDIT_CARD_H is already defines so it skips the whole definition.

Now you wouldn'd directly include a file twice like that, but it's common that one include file includes another and this stops any duplication definitions from happening.

The actual value is never used, only the fact that it's now *defined*

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `#pragma once`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once